# Comparing summation and integration for non monotonic function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

> $$P=\sum_{r=3n}^{4n-1} \frac{r^2+13n^2-7rn}{n^3}$$.
>   $$Q=\sum_{r=3n+1}^{4n} \frac{r^2+13n^2-7rn}{n^3}$$.
>   $$I=\int_{3}^{4} (x^2-7x+13) dx = \frac{5}{6}$$
>   Compare the values of $P,Q,I$

I know that for a strictly increasing function $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} f(x) \leq \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} f(x)dx$ and reverse for a strictly decreasing function. (I am also comfortable with changing the lower/upper limits)

However, the function here,  $x^2-7x+13$ is strictly decreasing from $x=3$ to $x=3.5$ and strictly increasing from $x=3.5$ to $x=4$.

I'm unable to compare the magnitude of "gain" in one interval with "loss" in the other to decide the overall outcome of the inequality.

I thought that the concavity of the function is $2$ so the derivative is increasing, and hence the latter parts change at a faster rate, hence the interval $3.5$ to $4$ outways the effect of the interval $3$ to $3.5$.

So I think that $P<I$ and $Q>I$. Is this correct?

How to solve this question rigorously?

Comment: Actually $P=Q$ because the $(3n)$th and $(4n)$th terms are both equal to $1/n$.

Comment: You may try to rewrite $\int^4_3(x^2-7x+13)\,dx =\sum^n_{j=0} \int^{3+\frac{j+1}{n}}_{3+\frac{j}{n}} x^2-7x+13 \,dx$ and compare terms...

Comment: Decreasing function concave up leads to overestimation and increasing function concave down leads to overestimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume $n$ is even for simplicity.

First, notice that you have a symmetric parabola centered at $x=3.5$. So by symmetry $P=Q$.

Let us only think about the definition of $P$. If instead of a parabolic $f$ we had a symmetric piecewise linear function (decreasing until $3.5$ and increasing after, see the picture below), the difference between the sum and integral from increasing and decreasing parts would exactly cancel out:

[image]

But for the parabola, because of its convexity, the overestimation from the left side is larger than the underestimation from the right side:

[image]

You can write a formal proof for this using the definition of convexity.

So the final answer is $P=Q>I$.

Comment: The pictorial proof is very nice! Thank you